# Postgres text column too large for an index - searching for IP address, so I don't think text search will work

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index-tuning, full-text-search, substring

I have a Postgres database with a column that has a large amount of text in it.  There are potentially multiple IP addresses in the text, as well as a lot of other text.

I need to do a query

```
WHERE value LIKE '%' || ipValue || '%'
```

which would be like:

```
WHERE value LIKE '%192.168.2.1%'
```

The column is too big for an index:

> [54000] ERROR: index row size 2872 exceeds btree version 4 maximum
>   2704 for index "rtfdata_value_index" Detail: Index row references
>   tuple (34153,51) in relation "rtfdata". Hint: Values larger than 1/3
>   of a buffer page cannot be indexed. Consider a function index of an
>   MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

An MD5 hash of the column value clearly will not work, and I don't think that a full-text index will allow me to search on the IP (since it's not a language word).

What can I do here?

My current best idea is to write a script that will create yet another table with a `record_id` and an `ip_address` column that will search each text column with a regex and pull out *all* the IPs and create 1 row per IP/record in this table.  Then I can join this table when looking for the IP, instead of the wildcard search on the large text column.

Comment: See the edit, there are possibly 0, 1 or > 1 IPs in the text, and the text can be quite large.

Comment: I agree with your last paragraph: extracting the IP addresses and store them separately (as `inet` or `cidr`) will most probably result in much better performance.

Answer (score 4):

You need a function which extracts the IP addresses into an array.  The regexp you gave doesn't work for me, so I came up with my own crude one, you will probably want to tweak it to suit yourself:

```
create or replace function extract_ip(text) returns text[] immutable language SQL as $$
  select array_agg(x[1]) from regexp_matches($1,'\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+','g')f(x) 
 $$;
create index on foobar using gin (extract_ip(value));
select * from foobar where extract_ip(value) && ARRAY['192.168.2.1'];
```